# IDW plot miscalculation

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-statistics, inverse-distance-weighted, ggplot

I want to perform IDW in R and plot it with ggplot.

Here is my code so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
kerpensample_df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\49151\\Desktop\\kerpentest0909x.csv",
                            header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",")
library(sf)
crs = st_crs("EPSG:32632")
head(kerpensample_df)
kerpensample_df_sf = st_as_sf(kerpensample_df, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = "OGC:CRS84")%>%
  st_transform(crs)

grd_100_sf <- kerpensample_df_sf %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>% 
  st_make_grid(
    cellsize = c(100, 100), # 100m pixel size
    what = "centers"
  ) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.))

i = idw(Z~1, 
        as(kerpensample_df_sf, "Spatial"),
        grd_100_sf,

ggplot(i, aes(x = "X", y = "Y", col =var1.pred)) + geom_point()
```

I don't get any errors, however the plot is not what I expected it to be and seems wrong:

[image]

Here is my sample data: https://ufile.io/myge36rv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(phylin)

## read in data from csv
kerpensample_df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\49151\\Desktop\\kerpentest0909x.csv",
                            header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",")

## make sf object of data, transforming to UTM for st_make_grid to work properly
crs = st_crs("EPSG:32632")
kerpensample_df_sf <- st_as_sf(kerpensample_df, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = "OGC:CRS84")%>%
  st_transform(crs)

## make grid
grd_100_sf <- kerpensample_df_sf %>% 
  st_make_grid(
    cellsize = c(100, 100), # 100m pixel size
    what = "centers"
  ) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.))

## get coordinates and value to interpolate from sf object
data <- kerpensample_df_sf %>% 
  cbind(. , st_coordinates(.)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  select(X,Y,Z)

## get the coordinates of the grid
grd <- grd_100_sf %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  select(X, Y)

## perform the IDW and join back the coordinates of the grid
i <- idw(data[,3], 
         data[,1:2],
         grd) %>% 
  cbind(grd)
  
## interpolated points, displayed in WGS84 coordinate system
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = i, mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y, col = Z), size=3) +
  coord_sf(crs=crs,  datum = st_crs(4326))

# tiled (filled) interpolation, displayed in WGS84 coordinate system
ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(data=i, aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=Z)) +
  coord_sf(crs=crs,  datum = st_crs(4326))

## make an sf object of i with WGS84
i_wgs_sf <- i %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('X','Y'), crs=crs) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: my apologies, I have forgot to include the IDW. I added it now. Thanks, but I already have a plot of my raw data. The IDW throws me the plot above with just a value in the middle.

Comment: I have updated my answer :)

Comment: It helped me alot! I have some follow-up questions, if you don't mind: a) what does the `-x` in  `select(x=X, y=Y, -x)` mean? b) looking at the x/y-coordinates of the plot, where do these come from? the actual coordinates of my data are around 6.6 and 50.9. c) in addition to b) how could I georeference this plot, in order to add it to a QGIS project?(my idea would be to georeference it manually, but for this I would need back the original coordinates. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the `-x` in an edit, as it's actually redundant when selecting the other columns. But using `select(-x)` would select everything except `x`.

Comment: regarding the coordinates, that is because they are projected from WGS84 to UTM Zone 32N (`st_transform(crs)`).

Comment: Upon trying the code mself, I get an error: `> data <- kerpensample_df_sf %>% 
+   cbind(. , st_coordinates(.)) %>% 
+   as.data.frame() %>% 
+   select(X, Y, Z, -x)`  Error:
     `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"data.frame"`

Comment: There is probably a conflict between libraries. If you have the `tidyverse` library loaded, use `dplyr::select`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129704/discussion-between-simonericmoon-and-matt).